# Cloud 9 MySql and MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, cloud9-ide

Just a simple question. Is it possible to use MySql Workbench to connect to a MySql database in a Cloud 9 IDE?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried myself, but Cloud9 seems to provide a full OS in the cloud, so if access to certain services is available (here MySQL TCP/IP via a port, default is 3306) then it should be possible to connect using MySQL Workbench. Better is of course to use SSH tunneling (TCP/IP, port 22). Just ask there to get access details.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud9 does not expose the MySQL port for security reasons so you won't be able to connect MySQL workbench to it.